# fabric textures messed up in Cycles even though preview seems fine

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, light

For some reason all my fabric textures come out messed up like this. I used textures from CC0textures.com and used the node wrangler add on to scale. I attached a picture of the final render. The wood floor, couch, pillows, and table are all messed up. The couch is also clipping the floor, even though I don't see that in lookdev mode. The left side seems perfectly fine, however. Does this have to do with the sun lamp that I used to light up the right? I lowered the max bounces on it from 1024 to 50. Do I need to scale the entire room up to fix the fabric problem? I also added a picture of my node setup for the glass.[image: LowQualityPictureofRender]

[image: GlassNodeSetup]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: I was using Lily's surface scraper and the displacement of the textures weren't scaled and were too large for the objects in my scene.